# OpenCV Camera Calibration - Using Kinect

Tags: opencv, kinect, camera-calibration

I am trying to do camera calibration using the OpenCV samples. But I am using a Kinect camera to do the calibration. Unlike some using built-in cameras, my kinect is connected through USB.

My first question is, in "default.xml" file,

```
<Input>"1"</Input> 
// To use an input camera -> give the ID of the camera, like "1"
```

Should I use Kinect camera's ID to replace the ID "1"?

The Kinect Camera ID will be like "USB\VID_0409&P~~~~~A\8&~~~~~~~&4".

---

Next question, I do not understand why because the build output doesn't really state out the error. But when I start the program, it will prompt out "Close the program" after processing awhile. I do point to point debug and I believed it has successfully reached "findChessboardCorners" function.

I create new Win32 empty console project, use the tutorial code of calibration and only change a bit for the properties of chessboard.

The result is:

[image: enterd image description here]

Can anyone help me with my problem? Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I think ID for USB devices is usually 0 or 1. Also, try running it as an admin. Additionally, check if the folder to which the output is generated is not "read-only".

Answer (score 0):

Follow these steps:

(1) Go to Device Manager
(2) Look for Kinect for Windows
(3) Right Click on the Camera one, select properties
(4) Go to Details
(5) Select Properties: Address and you'll see the device address.

In My case it was 00000003.

However the program still says inexistent input. Give it a try. It might not the same case for you as well.